# Installing Express.js on Mac

Tags: express, installation

I am trying to install express.js on my mac. I am following along with this page (http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html ).
When I put in the first thing it says to enter into terminal i get an error.

```
$ mkdir myapp
$ cd myapp
```

Running the first line results in the following.

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

Node is installed and when I check the terminal version it says v10.8.0

I don't know what to do troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Do not type `$`. Just type `mkdir myapp` then `cd myapp`. `$` is just indicating the prompt.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I love the front-end  but hate the back-end of web development and struggle setting up localhost and frameworks.